# Creating pairs from Group Membership Data

Tags: r, edges, sna

first of all, sorry for this probably stupid question but I'm getting really frustrated and desperate after 7 hours of using google and doing trail & error...

I have a list of user IDs and groups they belong to. I need a list of all combinations of users that share a group (edgelist to create a networkgraph). I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695409/create-weighted-graph-from-group-membership-data) right away and was really happy because it's exactly what I need. I've never used R before but it seemed like it could solve my problem very easily. The code provided in the other thread works perfectly fine as it is, but after I startet to customize it for my needs and especially my data input I ran into problems:

```
#import a csv, the column "group" consists of groupID, column "user" the userID
group <- read.csv("E:/r/input.csv")[ ,c('group')]
user <- read.csv("E:/r/input.csv")[ ,c('user')]
data.frame(group,user)
```

the output in R gives me this:

```
       group       user
1  596230112 1514748421
2  596230112 1529087841
3  596230112 1518194516
4  596230112 1514852264
5  596230112 1514748421
6  596230112 1511768387
7  596230112 1514748421
8  596230112 1514852264
9  596230112 1511768387
10 596231111 1535990615
11 596232665 1536087573
12 596232665 1488758238
13 596232665 1536087573
14 596234505 1511768387
15 596234505 1535990615
```

So far, so good! The next step should pair the users, e.g

```
1512748421 -> 1529097841
1512748421 -> 1518194516
```

and so on... The code I used is:

```
#create pairs
pairs <- do.call(rbind, sapply(split(user, group), function(x) t(combn(x,2))))
```

The error I get is:

```
Error : cannot allocate vector of size 5.7 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In combn(x, 2) :
  Reached total allocation of 3981Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In combn(x, 2) :
  Reached total allocation of 3981Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In combn(x, 2) :
  Reached total allocation of 3981Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In combn(x, 2) :
  Reached total allocation of 3981Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

The dataset I want to work with in the end is pretty big but for the start I tried to just have those 15 user/group entries I posted above and even that doesn't work... what am I not seeing here? The memory limit is already set to the maximum of my computer (4GB) and I also did everything the help-function or any R-website suggested.

R version 3.3.1, Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is

```
combn(x,2)
```

When `x` is an integer, `combn` creates the sequence `1 ... x` and returns all pairs from that sequence which will be a huge array if `x` is large.  This will happen if you have any group with a single user in it.

A solution is to filter out all groups that only have one user:

```
#create pairs
pairs <- do.call(rbind, sapply(Filter(function(x)
    length(x) > 1, split(user, group)), function(x) t(combn(x,2))))
```